# React-Native Animated: Spring Speed

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm having a look into the `Animated` library capabilities for my UI/UX and I'm hitting a wall trying to set the speed of an animation sequence.

The following occurs when an on-screen item is pressed. It 'pops' the item. This occurs over the space of a couple of seconds but I want to speed up the process. I presumed I could add an `Animated.timing...` to my parallel operation but I'm not getting anywhere with it :/

```
Animated.parallel([
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.spring(
        this.state.enter,
        { toValue: 0.9, tension:40, friction: 2 }
      ),
      Animated.spring(
        this.state.enter,
        { toValue: 1, tension: 40, friction: 10 }
      )
    ])
  ]).start();
```

Just so you know `this.state.enter` = `new Animated.Value(0.1)`

Comment: Doesn't the tension control the speed? -> From the docs: 

spring: Simple single-spring physics model that matches Origami.
friction: Controls "bounciness"/overshoot. Default 7.
tension: Controls speed. Default 40.

Comment: @NaderDabit I did look at that but the speed didn't seem to be significantly affected by the changes I made. I will revisit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook states in the official doc that when using Animated.spring you have to choose between two couples of parameters :

1) Bounciness and Speed (default values are 8 and 12)

OR

2) Tension and Friction (default values are 40 and 7)

So if you want to speed up the process, the best option would be to play around with Bounciness and Speed.

---

From the doc :

```
var springConfig;
    if (config.bounciness !== undefined || config.speed !== undefined) {
      invariant(
        config.tension === undefined && config.friction === undefined,
        'You can only define bounciness/speed or tension/friction but not both',
```

More info here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.29-stable/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js